How to Create a Persistent Notification Channel in Android to Access and Modify the Clipboard?
Hello StackOverflow community,
I'm working on a side project where I need to access and modify the clipboard on an Android device continuously. I've been exploring how applications like KDE Connect manage to monitor clipboard changes effectively. From what I understand, KDE Connect utilizes a persistent notification channel to keep a foreground service running, allowing it to interact with the clipboard even when the app isn't in focus.
 KDE Connect GitHub Repository: https://github.com/KDE/kdeconnect-kde
As a novice who hasn't delved into Android development for years, I'm finding it challenging to implement this functionality from scratch. Specifically, I'm looking to understand:

Creating a Persistent Notification Channel:
How to set up a notification channel that remains persistent to ensure my service isn't killed by the system.
Best practices for configuring the notification to comply with modern Android versions (especially Android 8.0 and above, which enforce notification channels).

Accessing and Modifying the Clipboard:
How to effectively monitor clipboard changes using a foreground service.
Methods to modify clipboard content programmatically while adhering to Android's security and privacy guidelines.

Utilizing Log Channels or Alternatives:
KDE Connect mentions using the "Log channel" for certain functionalities. How does this work, and is it applicable for clipboard access?
Are there alternative approaches to achieve similar results without relying on log channels?


What I've Tried:

Foreground Service with Notification: I've attempted to create a foreground service with a persistent notification, following standard Android documentation. However, the service doesn't seem to maintain its state as reliably as KDE Connect.

ClipboardManager Listener: Implemented ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener, but it only detects changes when the app is in the foreground.

Permissions: Added necessary permissions like FOREGROUND_SERVICE and POST_NOTIFICATIONS, but I'm unsure if there are additional permissions or settings required for continuous clipboard access.


Questions:

How can I create a robust persistent notification channel in Android that ensures my clipboard-monitoring service remains active in the background?

What are the best practices for accessing and modifying the clipboard in a background service without compromising user privacy or running into permission issues?

Can someone explain how KDE Connect utilizes the Log channel for clipboard access, and is there a modern equivalent approach I should consider?


Additional Information:
Android Version Target: I'm targeting Android 13 (API level 33) and above.
Development Environment: Android Studio with Kotlin.
Project Goal: To have a background service that monitors clipboard changes and can modify clipboard content as needed, similar to KDE Connect's functionality.
Any guidance, code snippets, or references to resources that can help me achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

In Android, a "Notification Channel" manages notifications. KDE mentions the ability to read/respond to notifications across platforms, so that is what the notification channel is for, to manage notifications.

How can I create a robust persistent notification channel in Android that ensures my clipboard-monitoring service remains active in the background?

What allows KDE to to do this is the BackgroundService class which tells Android that it will run in the background all of the time. For Android Oreo and later, this includes a persistent notification in the notification tray - not related to "notification channel" which manages the regular notifications.
Notification Channels are used to post notifications, remove them and also to separate them into groups. Apps may have different notification channels to manage those features. An app like KDE, for example, may want SMS notifications grouped in one channel/group then weather messages in another.

What are the best practices for accessing and modifying the clipboard in a background service without compromising user privacy or running into permission issues?

You should not be able to read other apps memory or logs, as this would be a huge security issue. Android will not allow you to read logs after JellyBean (3.3) because of security concerns. So the "sharing" will only happen when other apps use the Android clipboard feature which means they should be responsible for protecting privacy in their apps. You are responsible for doing it in yours. For example, a custom "clipboard" - something that may "copy/paste" but it is not the Android clipboard - for private data.

Can someone explain how KDE Connect utilizes the Log channel for clipboard access, and is there a modern equivalent approach I should consider?

It looks like KDE uses a lot of "old code" that will work on older Android versions, but not newer ones. So you do not really have a "LogChannel" in modern Android versions due to security concerns mentioned above. You will have to rely on users and app developers to understand how Android Clipboard works.
The "modern approach" may be to provide a keyboard that manages your clipboard data? Keyboards are a potential leak of private data, so they are separate apps, which would require your potential users to use your keyboard and your app. Some apps are signed by manufacturers to provide "convenience features" like what you sound interested in providing. But, as you hopefully can see, an "open" network that allows virtually any app to read logs, notifications, clipboard data, etc. can quickly be used for illicit and undesirable purposes.
Good luck!

Thank you for your answer Jim.
My understanding of what you're saying is that it's not possible to do it via a Log channels. I've been through the codebase a bit more in the mean time and from what I saw, they use an invisible floating activity that gets triggered with "onFocusHasChanged" and they can access the clipboard from there. When I copy text with KDE Connect, a toast is showed that the clipboard has been copied. I guess the persistent notification and the toast are there to be compliant? I'm trying to understand how exactly are they able to get a focus changed when the user copies.
